# Bitwise Interval Arithmetic

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, bit-manipulation

I've recently read an [interesting thread](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/value_range_propagation_for_logical_OR_108765.html) on the D newsgroup, which basically asks,

> Given two (signed) integers *a* ∈ [*a*<sub>min</sub>, *a*<sub>max</sub>], *b* ∈ [*b*<sub>min</sub>, *b*<sub>max</sub>], what is the tightest interval of *a*  |  *b*?

I'm think if interval arithmetics can be applied on general bitwise operators (assuming infinite bits). The bitwise-NOT and shifts are trivial since they just corresponds to -1 − *x* and 2<sup>*n*</sup> *x*. But bitwise-AND/OR are a lot trickier, due to the mix of bitwise and arithmetic properties.

**Is there a polynomial-time algorithm to compute the intervals of bitwise-AND/OR?**

---

Note:

- Assume all bitwise operations run in linear time (of number of bits), and test/set a bit is constant time.
- The brute-force algorithm runs in exponential time.
- Because `~(a | b) = ~a & ~b`, solving the bitwise-AND and -NOT problem implies bitwise-OR is done.
- Although the content of that thread suggests min{*a* | *b*} = max(*a*<sub>min</sub>, *b*<sub>min</sub>), it is not the tightest bound. Just consider `[2, 3] | [8, 9] = [10, 11]`.)
- Actually working on unsigned arithmetic is enough, as we can split a signed interval into negative and nonnegative subsets, and using de Morgan's laws and commutativity only the bitwise-AND, -OR and -AND-NOT cases on nonnegative intervals need to be solved.

Comment: I think the `sign` bit is definitely going to be a pain...

Comment: @Matt since I assumed infinite bits, any negative numbers should be prefixed by infinitely many 1's. But I accept unsigned cases as well.

Comment: I'm not convinced that your algorithm for computing bitwise-OR and -XOR yields the tightest possible interval in all cases.

Comment: @algorithmist: OK, you're right the -XOR algorithm is wrong because `a` and `b` appear twice. But for -OR, since bitwise-NOT is strictly monotonic I don't see a reason why it won't give the tightest interval.

Comment: i just wanna ask that if they weren't signed, they couldn't we jsut take the min of {a-min|b-min, a-max|b-max} ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an interval [a<sub>min</sub>, a<sub>max</sub>] of non-negative integers we can compute a bitwise minimum a<sub>0</sub>, where bits are independently set to 0 whenever that is possible within the interval. Similarly, we can compute a bitwise maximum a<sub>1</sub> where bits are set to 1 as much as possible in the interval. For [b<sub>min</sub>, b<sub>max</sub>] we do the same and get b<sub>0</sub> and b<sub>1</sub>. Then the result interval is [a<sub>0</sub> | b<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub> | b<sub>1</sub>].

It is easy to check for a bit which values it can take for an a from [a<sub>min</sub>, a<sub>max</sub>]. For bit n, if all bits m with m >= n agree in a<sub>min</sub> and a<sub>max</sub> then the value is forced, otherwise it can be 0 or 1.

This can be done in O(n).

The signed case is left as an exercise for the reader. The first step is to provide a definition what the bitwise operators mean for negative integers.

**Edit:** Unfortunately this is wrong: Consider the case where [a<sub>min</sub>, a<sub>max</sub>] = [b<sub>min</sub>, b<sub>max</sub>] = [1,2].
Then `a | b` can be either 1, 2 or 3, but the bitwise minimum is 0.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "bitwise minima"? `a_min & a_max`?

Comment: I see. But that seems no different from Rex's answer.

Comment: Rex writes it is O(n²), and he doesn't consider the interval separately. The result should of course be the same.

Answer (score 4):

Argh.  Are you sure these have to be signed integers?  That just brings up a pile of annoying cases where you have to flip things.

If we limit ourselves to unsigned integers, we can just walk down the bits to find the maximum.  Any bit above the highest bit set in `max(a_max , b_max)` obviously can't be on.  Assume without loss of generality that a_max > b_max.  Keep all the bits in a_max until we hit the highest bit in b_max.  Then keep all the bits of both until we have flexibility on at least one side (i.e. we can choose a number in the range allowed that will flip that bit).  If the other side cannot set that bit to 1, set it to 1 and keep going (setting one higher bit always beats setting all lower bits).  Otherwise, set your answer to (that bit - 1), which will places 1's in all the rest of the bits and you're done.

Now we do the same sort of thing for the minimum, except we avoid setting bits at every opportunity, but take every opportunity to pair bits if one side must set one.

This is O(n) in the number of bits if we can do math on the integers in O(1) time.  Otherwise, it's O(n^2).

Here's how it works on your example of [2,3] | [8,9]

```
101 -> 1xx works
10 to 11 -> x1x always set ; 11x doesn't fit in a so we're not done
11 can set last bit -> 111
100 -> 1xx must be set
10 to 11 -> x1x must be set ; 11x doesn't fit so we're not done
10 has xx0 as does 100 -> xx0 works -> 110
```

Edit: adding sign bits doesn't change the order of the algorithm, but it does require more annoying bookkeeping.  If you cannot get rid of a sign bit, then you flip min and max strategies (i.e. set vs. don't set bits).  If it's optional, the min is when you set it and then try to keep everything else unset; the max is when you unset it and then try to keep everything else set.

Second edit: here's another example; both ranges are [1001,1100]:

```
Must keep first bit -> 1xxx
Can set 2nd bit -> x1xx
Other _could have but did not need to_ set 2nd bit -> set 2nd bit -1 -> xx11
-> 1111 is max
Must keep first bit -> 1xxx
Neither needs 2nd bit -> x0xx
Neither needs 3rd bit -> xx0x
Both need 4th bit -> xxx1
-> 1001 is min
```

Comment: Signed arithmetic is not necessary. In fact, we can split the intervals into negative and nonnegative parts, and use bitwise-NOT to convert into nonnegative intervals. But then we need to deal with OR, AND and AND-NOT separately.

Comment: It's interesting that because of the `OR` logic, we can have in fine have a greater maximum. The `AND` logic would obviously produce the invert effect. `NOT` is a bijection so it should produce a range of similar length if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this for unsigned ints. The bounds are not perfect but are quite tight. For 100,000 random inputs, less than 200 were off by more than 0.1% from the actual interval computed by sampling. And it's always conservative (contains the real bounds).

The key is to use a FindLeadingOnes function as a building block. This allows expressing cases where significant bits match each other. This is important since an interval of integers has the property at the leading bits that match in the upper and lower bounds also match for all values in the interval. Thus, considering the leading matching bits allows computing the most significant bits of the output interval endpoints.

Also, for middle bits that are constant across one input interval but vary in the other input interval it's necessary to apply the operator to both the upper and lower bounds to get the interval for those bits. This is seen in iXOr.

Finally, the upper bound for AND is min(left.upper,right.upper) because no bit that's zero in one of those can be one in the output. Similar for OR's lower bound.

(Pay no attention to the ToInt and ToFloat stuff. I'm actually doing this on fixed point numbers. If you just make those functions be no-ops it'll work fine.

```
interval iAnd(const interval lv, const interval rv)
{
    unsigned int ll = ToInt(lv.lower), lu = ToInt(lv.upper), rl = ToInt(rv.lower), ru = ToInt(rv.upper);

    unsigned int lvx = FindLeadingOnes(~(ll ^ lu));
    unsigned int rvx = FindLeadingOnes(~(rl ^ ru));
    unsigned int constmask = (lvx | rvx);

    return interval(ToFloat((ll & rl) & constmask), ToFloat(std::min(lu, ru)));
}
```

and OR:

```
interval iOr(const interval lv, const interval rv)
{
    unsigned int ll = ToInt(lv.lower), lu = ToInt(lv.upper), rl = ToInt(rv.lower), ru = ToInt(rv.upper);

    unsigned int lvx = FindLeadingOnes(ll & lu) | FindLeadingOnes(~ll & ~lu);
    unsigned int rvx = FindLeadingOnes(rl & ru) | FindLeadingOnes(~rl & ~ru);
    unsigned int constmask = (lvx | rvx);

    return interval(ToFloat(std::max(ll, rl)), ToFloat((lu | ru) | ~constmask));
}
```

and XOR:

```
interval iXOr(const interval lv, const interval rv)
{
    unsigned int ll = ToInt(lv.lower), lu = ToInt(lv.upper), rl = ToInt(rv.lower), ru = ToInt(rv.upper);

    unsigned int lvx = FindLeadingOnes(ll & lu) | FindLeadingOnes(~ll & ~lu);
    unsigned int rvx = FindLeadingOnes(rl & ru) | FindLeadingOnes(~rl & ~ru);
    unsigned int constmask = (lvx | rvx);
    interval iout(ToFloat((ll ^ rl) & constmask), ToFloat((lu ^ ru) & constmask)); // Not sure which is larger; interval constructor sorts them.

    iout.extend(ToFloat(ToInt(iout.upper) | ~constmask)); // Now that the upper is known, extend it upward for the lsbs.

    return iout;
}
```

And here's my FindLeadingOnes (for my 16-bit fixed point. You can use more bits, though:

```
unsigned int FindLeadingOnes(unsigned int v)
{
    for(unsigned int mask = 0x8000; mask != 0xffff; mask |= mask >> 1u) {
        if ((mask & v) != mask)
            return (mask << 1u) & 0xffff;
    }

    return 0xffff;
}
```